# Looping of indices when running application

Tags: android-studio

It's been 10 minutes that When I try to run android studio it is always updating indices and it won't end. Gradle build has finished and yet it is still indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Files -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

This worked for me.